# Searching inside a USER model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, i have a search input that i want to use to look for users that can match what i typed inside the search input.

my user table has : firstname , name columns

let's say : i am looking for "Elthon John"

-i can type "Elthon" or "John" in the input (so i'll use an OR inside my rails query : name LIKE %search% or firstname like %search%)

- The problem is when i type the whole "Elthon John" inside my search input, how can i write a query that can find that line.

thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand your table layout.  User only has `firstname` and `name`? Do you mean `lastname`?  It would help if you showed your schema.

Comment: possible duplicate of [query finding columns that are substring of a string rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471384/query-finding-columns-that-are-substring-of-a-string-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if I understand correctly.

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |u|
  search_name = u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname
  if text_input == search_name
    #grab u.id and do what you need with it
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, how can i make it return the same 'thing' as find() (defualt method of rails)?

Comment: `User.find_by(id: u.id)`

Comment: Just put the code you want to run for each id within the comment I left in the if statement.

Comment: can i pass an array to the find_by() method to return all the lines with the id's in the array?

Comment: You can always check the method documentation or test it in your app to find out.  This discussion is getting a little off-topic from the question.